# Rails Production Log - Sometimes requests are logged and sometimes not

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, logging

I am having troubles finding out the reason my application won't work. I am using apache + passenger.

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.log_level = :debug
```

The problem is sometimes request are logged and sometimes not.

I.E.

```
Request: GET /a/b

# tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
cache: [GET /a/b] miss

# tail -f log/production.l
Started GET "/a/b" for 189...

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/a/b"):
[... stack trace ...]
```

Nice. That is exactly what I expected to see in my log. But the second time I try the same request (from another browser so I rule out any local cache), I see the same output in the apache error log, but the production.log is unchanged.

If I try a different request, I can see the output in both logs.

```
Request: GET /a/b/c

# tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
cache: [GET /a/b/c] miss

# tail -f log/production.l
Started GET "/a/b/c" for 189...

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/a/b/c"):
[... stack trace ...]
```

Looks like there is a cache that won't log "redundant" warnings and errors.

Well, the question is, how do I log everything?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the reason:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4277